# Cannot find module Ionic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, npm

I try to execute ionic info but it show some error

```
[ERROR] Error loading @ionic/react package.json: Error: Cannot find module '@ionic/react/package'
```

here my ionic info

```html
C:\Users\MyPC>ionic info
[ERROR] Error loading @ionic/react package.json: Error: Cannot find module '@ionic/react/package'

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI       : 5.4.5
   Ionic Framework : not installed

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.8.1
   native-run  : 0.2.9

System:

   NodeJS : v10.15.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Comment: You have to install Ionic framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the Ionic Framework - try running `npm install ionic -g` and then rerun `ionic info`.